# NSTextView backgroundColor attribute

Tags: swift, macos, syntax-highlighting, background-color, nstextview

I cannot get background color working on my NSTextView. I use the following attributes:

```
myTextView.typingAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)!,
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.textColor,
    NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 2,
] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]

myTextView.selectedTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.systemRed,
                           NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: NSColor.systemYellow]
```

Text is correctly displayed as indicated above, when I select text the font changes to red, as expected. But the background color of the text does not change to yellow. It happens both in dark mode and light mode (Mojave).

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I found what is causing this. I am using a custom `NSLayoutManager` where I override `drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at _: NSPoint)`.  However, I failed to call its super, therefore cancelling out the backgroundColor attribute.

Comment: You don't set the background color anywhere above except for the selection, why do you expect it to work?

Comment: The background is yellow in my test app.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it’s not working for me because I am using a custom layoutManager. I’ll look into it.

Comment: Yeah, I am getting yellow background too!

Comment: Indeed, it was the custom LayoutManager that causes this. See more info in the edit to my question